# C# dynamic form editing

Tags: c#, loops

this is my first post.
i am creating a c# application with 89 textboxes. the textboxes are named "Box#"
how can i change the values of the text boxes within a loop? Somthing like this:

```
for (int y = 0; y < 89; y++)
{
    "Box"+y.Text = "somthing";
}
```

Comment: WPF, Windows forms, or Web?

Comment: how do you insert these textboxes?

Comment: How dynamic are your textboxes? If you are placing all of them via a WYSIWYG editor, then I recommend you reference each textbox by name, as this enforces a strict design policy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could check the `Type` of the controls on the form, if the `Type` is a `TextBox` then, simply adjust the test (VIA a loop).

Code snippet;

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ChangeTextBoxes();
    }

public void ChangeTextBoxes()
    {
        foreach (var c in this.Controls.OfType<TextBox>())
        {
            c.Text = @"New Value";
        }
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

You're creating a new `String` object when you use `"Box"`. What I would recommend is putting all of your `TextBox` objects into a list.

```
List<TextBox> boxes = new List<TextBox>();

// Add all of your text boxes.

foreach (TextBox box in boxes) {
    box.Text = "This will change the text";
}
```

Comment: Where's `singleItem` come from?

Answer (score 0):

If you are making this changes in a View (Client side using Javascript), use the "eval()" function.

Something similar to this:

```
eval('Box' + count + '.Text = "'+newText+'";');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you create the text boxes programmatically, you could bind their `Text` properties to a `DataTable`, which would give you some nice maintainability features:

```
DataTable _tbValues;

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _tbValues = new DataTable();
    string[] cells = new string[89];
    for (int i = 0; i < 89; i++)
    {
        _tbValues.Columns.Add(String.Format("Box{0}", i));
        var tb = new TextBox();
        tb.Name = String.Format("Box{0}", i);
        tb.DataBindings.Add("Text", _tbValues, String.Format("{0}", tb.Name));
        tb.Top = i * 20;
        this.Controls.Add(tb);
    }
    _tbValues.Rows.Add(cells);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _tbValues.Rows[0].ItemArray = Enumerable
        .Repeat(DateTime.Now as object, _tbValues.Columns.Count)
        .ToArray();
    _tbValues.AcceptChanges();
}
```